# intellisense errors when using visual studio force include

Tags: c++, visual-studio, intellisense

I am experiencing an issue when I attempt to use the visual studio option force include (/FI) with a precompiled header file. When I compile the following source code below it compiles correctly but it shows incorrect errors stating the data type of the arguments are undefined via intellisense. I am wonder how this could be fixed?

```
void startup(HMODULE hModule, DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
}
```

I have made sure to include the windows header in the precompiled header.

Comment: By including the file normally?

Comment: well yes but wouldn't this completely remove the purpose of using a precompiled header? or am I not understanding this properly..?

Comment: You can use precompiled headers without FI, but this particular situation seems more an issue with intellisense. Might need to report bug to MS.

Answer (score 0):

I force include the windows.h file, and the intellisense can work as normal. My visual studio is 16.9.4.
[image]